Laravel API testing on PUT request
can anyone help. I am trying to test my Laravel API and every time I'm doing a PUT request on cart an error message 401 is showing. There was no problem with my credentials as I've double checked the users table and it matched with what I put on registration and login credentials. can anyone check my code I want to know if i've missed some important codes. thank you!
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = validator($request->all(), [
            "name" => "required",
            "password" => "required",
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return $this->BadRequest($validator, "all fields are required");
        }

        $validated = $validator->validated();

        if (!auth()->attempt([
                filter_var($validated["name"], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ? "email" : "name" => $validated["name"],
                "password" => $validated["password"]
            ])){
            return $this->Unauthorized();
        }

        $user = auth()->user();
        $user->profile;

        return $this->ok([$user,],"Logged in succesfully");
        
    }

Route::middleware("auth:api")->get("/checktoken", [AuthController::class, "checktoken"])->middleware("auth:api");
Route::post("/register", [AuthController::class, "register"]);
Route::post("/login", [AuthController::class, "login"]);
Route::post("/status", [OrderController::class, "status"])->middleware("auth:api");

Route::middleware('auth:api')->group(function () {
Route::get('/cart', [CartController::class, 'index']);
Route::post('/cart', [CartController::class, 'add']);
Route::put('/cart/{cartId}', [CartController::class, 'update']);
Route::delete('/cart/{cartId}', [CartController::class, 'remove']);
Route::post('/cart/checkout', [CartController::class, 'checkout']);

 public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = validator($request->all(), [
            "name" => "required|min:4|max:32|alpha_dash|string|unique:users",
            "email" => "required|email|max:255",
            "password" => "required|min:8|max:64|string|confirmed",
            "first_name" => "required|string|max:64|min:1|string",
            "last_name" => "required|string|max:64|min:1|string"
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return $this->BadRequest($validator);
        }
        //this creates the user login information in the users table
        $user = User::create($validator->safe()->only("name", "email", "password"));
        $user->profile()->create($validator->safe()->except("name", "email", "password"));

        return response()->json([$user, "account was succesfully created!" ], 201);
    }


your issue is with put request, yet you shared no details on the request itself, did you send the token ? did you try the other route requiring authentification ? did you send in your form _method=put ?

I think you may be confusing two different types of route authentication.
Internal API
Endpoints that are only accessible from your Laravel frontend, defined in web.php. Uses session based authentication. User logs in once, and every subsequent request includes a cookie that is used to resolve the user.
External API
Endpoints that are accessible from outside your Laravel application, defined in api.php. Does not persist authenticated user. Each API request must pass a token used to resolve the user.

If this case, it looks like you're defining an internal API, but you're using auth:api middleware which tells Laravel to use the api guard for authentication. You should probably be using the auth:web guard which looks something like this by default:
// config/auth.php

'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],

This tells Laravel to persist the authenticated user using the session driver and validate the user email & password via the users table.

If that isn't the problem, try sharing more details about your guard, middleware, and API request setup.
Also, you could avoid these authentication headaches by using a Laravel starter kit like Breeze or Jetstream.
